# Getting exception : Unknown string format:

Tags: python, python-dateutil

I am trying to  extract dates from text using dateutil library (Python 3.7)

I want to extract all dates from text using code below.

```py
import dateutil.parser as dparser

text = 'First date is 10 JANUARY 2000 and second date is 31/3/2000'

dt = dparser.parse(text, fuzzy=True, dayfirst=True, default=datetime.datetime(1800, 1, 1))
```

But getting following exception

> Unknown string format: First date is 10 JANUARY 2000 and second date
> is 31/1/2000

Please let me know any way to extract multiple dates in the text.

Comment: It seems that it expects only 1 date in the input, and it won't return ALL dates from an arbitrary string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using [datefinder](https://pypi.org/project/datefinder/)?

```py
import datefinder

string_with_dates = '''
    First date is 10 JANUARY 2000 and second date is 31/3/2000
'''

matches = datefinder.find_dates(string_with_dates)
for match in matches:
    print(match)

Output:
2000-01-10 00:00:00
2000-03-31 00:00:00
```